# What does _("write error") mean?

Tags: c

In Debian 8's source code /source/procps-3.3.9/lib/fileutils.c line 38 is:
    char const *write_error = _("write error");

I am confused about the _("write error") part. Google showed that result on variable naming convention or library reserved names, but nothing about when _ was on the right side of = and before a () quoted string.

I also put this line into a simplest test program as only useful line then had compilation failed saying:

> ```
> test.c:5:20: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>     char const *str = _("test string");
>                     ^
>
> test.c:5:20: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
> /tmp/cczQpqTh.o: In function `main':
> test.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `_'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Does anyone know what `_(" ")` format means?

Comment: `_` is a perfectly legal _name_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the standard way to mark up strings for translation using [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), a free software translation tool.

[The `_()` macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Mark-Keywords.html#Mark-Keywords) is found by an external tool which extracts the text to make it translatable, as well as (at run-time) do look-ups to replace the literal with the necessary translation.

There is nothing special about the name `_`, it's just a very short but perfectly valid C identifier. Perhaps it's a bit iffy to begin a public symbol with an underscore, I'm not sure right now.

The error you're getting is because your test program very likely fails to include the [`<libintl.h>` header](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Importing.html#Importing) (part of gettext, of course) which declares this macro. Thus you get the normal "undefined reference" error, as expected.

Comment: I read somewhere on SO that symbols starting with underscore are not recommended when left to the linker. A macro isn't a problem though.

Comment: also, can you provide a way to fix OP issue? why isn't the macro defined in this public & working source code?